# sentence in Livy 33/LLPSI

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, livius

Chapter 50 of *Lingua Latina per sē illustrāta: Rōma Æterna* contains this from Livy 33:

> . . . mājus gaudium fuit quam quod ūniversum hominēs acciperent.

What is *ūniversum* doing here? Its ending suggests that it's modifying *gaudium* to mean "universal joy," but putting an adjective in a clause subordinate to the clause in which its noun appears seems very strange.

I can't figure out anything else, though, for it to mean.

Comment: I believe that some commentators suggest an alternative reading as universim, which would make some sort of sense.

Comment: Ah—that would at the very least offer a way to parse the sentence grammatically.

Comment: [This translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Liv.+33+32&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0164) has "joy greater than men could grasp in its entirety".

Comment: That would fit with *universim*.

Comment: Could be "as a whole."

Comment: I can see it working as an adjective: "maius gaudium fuit quam quod universum [gaudium] homines acciperent."

Comment: Yes, pretty sure that translation is reading *universum*.

Comment: Right. But that's what I don't get: putting an adjective in a clause subordinate to the clause in which its noun appears seems very strange. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Would it be an adverb in this case then?

Comment: @JoelDerfner Only in the English. It's not at all uncommon for Latin to use adjectives where we would place the emphasis on the verb. *Marcus iratus clamavit* = lit. Marcus, angry, shouted; but better in English "Marcus angrily shouted." I don't have any exact references offhand, but I see nothing strange about an adjective in the subordinate modifying a noun in the primary.

Answer (score 3):

An adjective of number, a superlative or an emphatic adjective that describes the antecedent is often put in the relative clause (or "attracted to the Clause of the Relative", as Kennedy phrases it).  The adjective will agree with the relative pronoun.
Examples:

> si veniat Caesar cum copiis **quas** habet **firmissimas**
>
> if Caesar comes with the **strongest** troops **that** he has
>
> librum **quem** **recentissimum** habebat mihi dedit
>
> he gave me the **newest** book **that** he had

So, the position of the adjective is entirely normal.  Thus, I would put *universum* with *gaudium* – universal joy (*pace* Evan T. Sage who has evidently translated it as an adverb!).

Given that a comparative (*quam*) +/- a relative pronoun + the subjunctive suggests a result/consecutive clause, a literal translation could be:

> there was a universal joy so great with the result that the men
>   couldn’t accept it

or more polished:

> there was universal joy greater than what the men could accept

Ref: *Kennedy's Revised Latin Primer*, p.156, point 332, note 2; and Colebourn, *Latin Sentence and Idiom*, p.115, point 375; and Morwood, *Latin Grammar*, p. 100, point 6

Comment: My (idiomatically translated) understanding of the phrase is different: "The joy was too great for men to accept it entirely." A subtle but important difference, since you seem to imply that no man can accept it...

Comment: But @brianpck, now we're back to square one! :)  I guess universum could be an adverb but using Occam's razor, I reasoned thus: an adverbial accusative is more likely to be found in poetry (Kennedy); my dictionary didn't list universum as an adverb; there are adverbial forms, universe and universim, but they mean "in general"; "entirety" might be better rendered with totus; there could be a textual variant but who knows; while the explanation for the placement of universum was simple; moreover, it's a common, well-documented Latin construction.

Comment: No, I agree it's an adjective, but I was translating it as an adverb. To preserve the awkward structure in English: "The joy was greater than that men could receive it whole."

Comment: How about "there was complete joy, more than the men could possibly take on board"?